# Decompressing text file with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression

I need to load a 2MB text file into a JS variable. I had the idea that if I was able to compress that file and then inflate it, that would save a lot of bandwidth. What is the preferred method of compressing the text file and then decompressing into a variable with jquery/JS?

Edit: Changed the title to clarify.

Comment: Compressing on the client side is completely pointless in terms of saving bandwidth, as you'd have to download the compressed file from the server anyway. Do the compression on the server. That being said, 2Mb of text is a ***ridiculous*** amount of data to be loading in to JS. I'd strongly suggest you rethink this entire idea as there's several flaws already.

Comment: The preferred option would be not to load a 2Mb file into a JS variable...  is there a use for this?

Comment: Yeah, for autocomplete without pinging the db multiple times. I'd rather use bandwidth and have client-side autocomplete vs increased server cpu load. To clarify regarding the first comment, the compression is server-side. The uncompression has to be client side. I should have made the title clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There try this here

```js
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('#div').html(data.replace('n',''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I know how to load the file, but I was hoping to zip it on server and unzip it into variable with jquery. That way instead of having to download 2MB it can be much less.